# D4024 followed by LNK1181 when compiling npm installation

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-c++

It's been around a month since I last modified my Discord.js bot, and as I was pushing updates to the bot recently, it throws me an error regarding unable to find the specified music module. I decided to uninstall and reinstall the said module, and I received D4024 fatal error, followed by LNK1181. Here's how it looks like:

```
C:\TankieBot Dummy\node_modules\ref>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\Spades Hiroki\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_mo
dules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
  Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 12.00.8168 for 80x86
  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1984-1998. All rights reserved.

  cl /


CL : Command line warning D4024: unrecognized source file type '/', object file assumed [C:\TankieBot Dummy\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
  Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.00.24210.0
  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

  /out:.exe
  /
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file '/.obj' [C:\TankieBot Dummy\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj]
```

and even more, I have an exactly zero idea what has gone wrong:

```
C:\TankieBot Dummy\node_modules\node-opus>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\Spades Hiroki\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\n
ode_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
  Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 12.00.8168 for 80x86
  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp 1984-1998. All rights reserved.

  cl /

     p

     _

     .

     l

     o


CL : Command line warning D4024: unrecognized source file type '/', object file assumed [C:\TankieBot Dummy\node_modules\node-opus\build\deps\libopus.vcxproj]
CL : Command line warning D4024: unrecognized source file type 'p', object file assumed [C:\TankieBot Dummy\node_modules\node-opus\build\deps\libopus.vcxproj]
CL : Command line warning D4024: unrecognized source file type '_', object file assumed [C:\TankieBot Dummy\node_modules\node-opus\build\deps\libopus.vcxproj]
CL : Command line warning D4024: unrecognized source file type '.', object file assumed [C:\TankieBot Dummy\node_modules\node-opus\build\deps\libopus.vcxproj]
CL : Command line warning D4024: unrecognized source file type 'l', object file assumed [C:\TankieBot Dummy\node_modules\node-opus\build\deps\libopus.vcxproj]
CL : Command line warning D4024: unrecognized source file type 'o', object file assumed [C:\TankieBot Dummy\node_modules\node-opus\build\deps\libopus.vcxproj]
  Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.00.24210.0
  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

  /out:.exe
  /
  p
  _
  .
  l
  o
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file '/.obj' [C:\TankieBot Dummy\node_modules\node-opus\build\deps\libopus.vcxproj]
```

It was weird considering months ago there were no such issue, and it just popped out for an exactly no reason. I've tried reinstalling VC++ 2015 Build Tools and it still retains the same issue. Copied CL.exe along with C1.dll and C2.dll gives me zero luck, it just pops `error MSB6006: "CL.exe" exited with code -1073741701`.

The only thing I remembered after pushing updates as of last month was installing Unity and Blender, though I'm not too sure if that actually do something sneaky.

Any kind of guides are appreciated.

Comment: Tagged [PowerShell] because ..?

Comment: ah my bad, I probably added that by mistake.